# How to give each tab item of tab layout some shape?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, tabitem

I want to make a design as given below using android tab layout[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6qcB.png)

Comment: please share your xml and problem you faced with xml

Comment: The image I've shared already in the description, I want to make as it is. I haven't started it yet, I'm new at this.

Comment: I think you should first try your attempt if any problem encounter we are here to help you

Comment: Okay, I'll let you know

Comment: happy to help :)